# How can my variable paradoxically both an ndarray and also a dict?

Tags: python, json, numpy, glove

I am trying to get my GloVe vectors for a machine learning model, without having to load the model every time. Therefore I would like to save the glove_model dictionary to a json file such that it can be loaded elsewhere after its initial construction.

However I keep getting this error: "TypeError: Object of type ndarray is not JSON serializable" - full error below. Thanks!

```
import numpy as np 
import json

def make_glove_model():
    ''' 
    Load gloVe pre-trained vectors. 
    Dict keys = tokens (strings); values = word vectors (np arrays of length 50). 
    ''' 
    filename = 'Data/glove_twitter_50d.txt'
    print("gloVe vectors loading . . .")
    with open(filename,'r', encoding='utf8') as foo:
        gloveModel = {}
        for line in foo:
            splitLines = line.split()
            word = splitLines[0]
            wordEmbedding = np.array([float(value) for value in splitLines[1:]])
            gloveModel[word] = wordEmbedding
            
    # Get average of word vectors to be used for unseen words, per GloVe author
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8') as foo:
        for i, line in enumerate(foo):
            pass
    n_vec = i + 1
    hidden_dim = len(line.split(' ')) - 1
    
    vecs = np.zeros((n_vec, hidden_dim), dtype=np.float32)
    
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8') as foo:
        for i, line in enumerate(foo):
            vecs[i] = np.array([float(n) for n in line.split(' ')[1:]], dtype=np.float32)
    
    avg_vec = np.mean(vecs, axis=0)
    print(len(gloveModel),"gloVe vectors loaded.")
    return gloveModel, avg_vec

glove_model, avg_vec = make_glove_model()
with open('glove_model.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(glove_model, f)
```

This throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\Documents on D\Machine_Learning\Sentiment_Analysis\import_glove.py", line 43, in <module>
    json.dump(glove_model, f)

  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tfgpu\lib\json\__init__.py", line 179, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:

  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tfgpu\lib\json\encoder.py", line 431, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)

  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tfgpu\lib\json\encoder.py", line 405, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks

  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tfgpu\lib\json\encoder.py", line 438, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)

  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tfgpu\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '

TypeError: Object of type ndarray is not JSON serializable
```

Yet when I check data type,

```
type(glove_model)
Out[17]: dict

type(avg_vec)
Out[18]: numpy.ndarray
```

Comment: `glove_model` is a dict which contains a `numpy.ndarray` as a value. Therefore, you cannot just naively serialize it with JSON. Is there some particular reason you are using JSON? You could just use `pickle`.

Comment: Thank you! No specific reason, just that I've basically never used it. Getting pretty confused already. Is it possible to pickle something and then load it in a different module? I'm trying to avoid having to build the glove_model vectors every time I run another script. I would just like to save and load them.

Comment: Yes, `pickle` is a binary serialization format that can serialize arbitrary python objects, unlike JSON, which is limited to `str`, `int`/`float` `dict` and `list`, although, you can define handlers for the JSON encoder etc, but if you don't *have* to use JSON that's a lot of work for little gain, and then you still have to deal with the deserialization (you'd have to write code to handle that to get back the types you need).

Answer (score 3):

I think this is because your dict contains a `numpy.ndarray`.

```
Embedding = np.array([float(value) for value in splitLines[1:]])
gloveModel[word] = wordEmbedding
```

Comment: I see! Thank you, I suppose I will need to figure something else out